# Iterating through an array only gets the first value in Swift Playground

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-playground

I'm aware this is a pretty basic question but it has me stumped and figure out why. I have an array of names and what to iterate through them to get them all as single names, although when I do so using the `for in` loop it just produce the first name, my code:

```
var arrayA = ["Mike", "James", "Stacey", "Steve"]
var str = String()
for array in arrayA {
    str = array 
    println(str)//Just prints steve
}
```

The problem is it only prints steve, I want to be able to access all the name singley

This is what I am seeing:

[image]

Comment: It's only printing "Steve"? Is this in a Playground? If so and you're viewing the output via QuickLook, you have to click the "All Values" button in the results view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using a playground, you might need to change the view in order to see all the results..

You need to hover over the quick view display in order to find the "All Values" icon.

[image]

---

It looks like this may have changed in **Xcode 7** - as @MikeMeyers mentions in the comments, you need to right click on the quick view window and select the value history option.

[image]

Comment: If you hover over the quick view display, do you not see the two icons appear top right?

Comment: This seems like it might changed with Xcode 7. I'm not seeing the two icons but instead (in a bit of a UI failure) I need to right-click on the quick view display window and then choose from the pop-up menu.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce what you're saying:

```
rnapier:~$ swift
Welcome to Swift version 1.2. Type :help for assistance.
  1> var arrayA = ["Mike", "James", "Stacey", "Steve"]
  2. var str = String()
  3. for array in arrayA {
  4.     str = array
  5.     println(str)//Just prints steve
  6. }
Mike
James
Stacey
Steve
arrayA: [String] = 4 values {
  [0] = "Mike"
  [1] = "James"
  [2] = "Stacey"
  [3] = "Steve"
}
str: String = "Steve"
```

This prints all the values, and leaves `str` assigned to the last element. It's unclear here why you're using `str` at all, but I believe it does what you ask.

If I were writing this loop, I would recommend:

```
let arrayA = ["Mike", "James", "Stacey", "Steve"]
for elem in arrayA {
    println(elem)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs just fine - it iterates over all array elements, and it prints them all.

I notice a bit of redundancy though - it can be rewritten more concisely as:

```
var arrayA = ["Mike", "James", "Stacey", "Steve"]
for element in arrayA {
    println(element)//Just prints steve
}
```